# Is there a reason my string changes when using subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python, string, amazon-web-services, subprocess

I need the string to be placed inside a variable to look **exactly** like this:

`'{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"<bucketname>","Name":"<docname>","Version":"<version>"}}'`

the `'`s need to be exactly where they are when the string is used later.

so, I define it like this

`aws_object = """'{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"%s","Name":"%s","Version":"1"}}'""" % (AWS_BUCKET, AWS_DOCUMENT_NAME)`

this is the only method I've found that will allow the variables to be placed inside the string while being able to use `'` and `"` as needed. printing the variable to the console results in the string looking perfect.

however, using `aws_object` later on results in the string looking like

`\'{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"testing-bucket","Name":"contract.pdf","Version":"1"}}\'']'`

in the console, when used in `subprocess.check_output` like so:

`job_id = subprocess.check_output(["aws textract start-document-text-detection --document '{}'".format(aws_object)], shell=True)`

so there's some extra characters in there, maybe from using `"""` in the `aws_object` or something.

the error returned says `Unable to get object metadata from S3.`, because the object passed  into `start-document-text-detection` is incorrectly formatted.

how can I achieve the desired string formatting to make AWS CLI happy?

Comment: You mean you just want to serialize the data to JSON with something like `json.dumps()`?

Comment: @roganjosh didn't even think of that. will try it

Comment: You've gone all around the houses and made things so much harder for yourself here

Comment: @roganjosh not intentionally.

Comment: Obviously not :)

Comment: @roganjosh the outcome is the same, being as I need a stringified JSON with single quotes around it inside the command

Answer (score 0):

made it work by doing the following:

```
aws_object = {"S3Object":{"Bucket":AWS_BUCKET,"Name":AWS_DOCUMENT_NAME,"Version":"1"}}
aws_object = json.dumps(aws_object)
...
try:
  job_id = subprocess.check_output(["aws textract start-document-text-detection --document '{}'".format(aws_object)], shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print(e)
```

this kept the AWS CLI happy because these conditions were met:

- each key in the JSON object was surrounded by `"`s
- the entire JSON object in the command was surrounded by `'`s

edit:

the `json.dumps()` is important here, because without it, the object is rendered with `'`s around the keys and AWS CLI doesn't like that.